# admob 6.4.1 not working on gingerbread 2.3

Tags: android, admob, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am trying to put admob ads in app am working on. I have included admob sdk in libs folder and also did java build path. The ads are shown in android 4.2.2 but doesnt appear in android 2.3. What can be the problem here?

Note that i have given all the necesary permisisions as well as configchanges

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Do you get any error in android 2.3 ?

Comment: What is your target build API?

Comment: I have set the target to 17 and minSdk is 8

Comment: @GrlsHu I do get some error saying leaked window size and error inflating adview. I dont remember the error precisely as am away from my work system right now

Comment: Post your logcat when it fails in Gingerbread

Comment: @william i get this error                                            10-15 20:42:21.049: W/webcore(25238): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
10-15 20:42:21.059: E/Ads(25238): IOException connecting to ad url.

Comment: Post the *full* stacktrace up above in your question. What you are showing us is not enough to debug this. But note that a quick google shows lots of similar questions https://www.google.com.au/search?q=android+admob+ioexception+connecting+to+ad+url&oq=IOException+connecting+to+ad+url&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l2.6913j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really embarrassed to find this out, but the problem was related to adblocker app. The gingerbread phone had adblocker app, but i had uninstalled it. What i didn't know was that even if its uninstalled, the hosts files are changed and we need to revert it back to original one by disabling adblocker again.   That was really stupid of me :(

Now ads are displayed properly. Thanks to everyone who took trouble to help me out. :)